# C++ inheritance: defining a pointer to either derived or base class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance

If I have a derived class from a base class and I'd like to assign a pointer to an object of either of them based on a flag, what should be the definition of the pointer referring to the chosen object.

Example:

```
void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   class Base B;
   class Derived D;
   class Base *P;  /* My question is output this definition */
   int flag;   /* This will be an input */
   if(flag)
      P = &B;   /* Should refer to the base class B */
   else
      P = &D;   /* Should refer to the derived class D
   /* Then I'd use P in the rest of my code */ 
}
```

My question is how would the class pointer P be defined to be able to refer to either B (the base class) or D the derived class) based on the flag `flag' ?

Comment: This is fine so long as `Derived` is derived from `Base`. What is not working for you?

Comment: Thanks jxh. I was trying to make sure of my solution. I was confused about the definition part. Is it ok to define P as a pointer to the Base class and then assign it a pointer to the derived class ? By the way, would the other way around work as well (i.e. defining P as follows:   class Derived *P;) ?

Comment: You are not allowed to make that assignment, since `B` is not a `Derived`.

Comment: This is possible but the pointer can only be used to call functions declared in B. If you want to call different functions in D then you'll need to learn about virtual functions.

Comment: Unless you're your going to have code crossing binary boundaries and need compatibility between different versions of your code, there's not too much to worry about.  You can use a base class pointer type to refer to your base class and derived classes.  Or a reference instead.  :)

Comment: QuentinUK: This is exactly what I want to do. The derived class will have functions that are not declared in the base class. And I need the pointer P to call all functions in either the base class or the derived class based on the flag, so how can this be done ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you code is of the basic form:

```
class Base
{
public:
   virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Derived : public Base
{};
```

Then a `Derived` is a `Base` according to the language rules, and therefore a pointer to the base class can hold either a `Derived` or a `Base`.

```
Base* p = nullptr;
Base b;
Derived d;

if(flag == UseBase)
{    
   // Works
   p = &b;
}
else if(flag == UseDerived)
{
   // also works
   p = &d;
}
```

That said, a `Base` is not a `Derived`, so the reverse (`Derived* pd = &b`) will not work as written above.

Comment: Thanks Chad. Do I have to use virtual inside the base class ?

Comment: If you ever intend to use dynamic memory allocation (`new`), and will deallocate memory (`delete`) though a base-class pointer, then yes, the `virtual` destructor is required for the appropriate behavior to be guaranteed.

Comment: Understanding virtual methods is very important.  You probably want to have your methods virtual.

With regard to the pointer thing, if possible, references can be even better than pointers.  Eg `Base& myClassRef = (flag == kUseBaseClass ? b : d);`

In C++ you really only want to use pointers if there's a compelling reason, like a value of NULL means something.

Comment: Chad: Does this syntax allow the pointer p to call functions in the derived class d that are not members of the base class b ?